# JSONDOC Creation showing exception

Tags: java, documentation, jsondoc

I want to document my REST Based API, so for that I searched  the google and found this http://jsondoc.org/

I am using GuiceConfig to inject the objects and there I used the method **JSONDocUtils.getApiDoc(servletContext, version, basePath);** inside GuiceConfig.java

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    LOGGER.info("Initializing Context : configuring juice Injector");
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new Module[] { new PropertiesModule(),
     ................       
    } });

    ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    servletContext.setAttribute(Injector.class.getName(), injector);
    System.out.println("JSON DOC UTILS......");
    JSONDocUtils.getApiDoc(servletContext, "1.0", "jsondoc");
}
```

Code is throwing an exception that **"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsondoc/core/util/JSONDocUtils"** but in reality the jar I have specified  as a dependency like this

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jsondoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jsondoc-core.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

And yes it is there in the lib folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now JSONDoc is available on maven central, so the best thing is that you upgrade it to latest version and eventually follow the migration notes on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the dependencies of jsondoc are available at runtime ?

I suspect the one missng to be **org.reflections:reflections**.
See full [dependencies list](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsondoc/jsondoc-core/1.0.3)